# Routing only with specified points

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgrouting, dijkstra

I'm very new to GIS and to `pgRouting`. We're implementing a Routing system in our app and we need to route between points that we'll define ourself.

So far, we have a working `pgRouting` on `Postgis` (on `Postgres`) and a `Spring boot application` to call pgRouting's methods. We managed somehow to download from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de) and import OSM files into the running database using `osmttools` to reduce it's size, but there still are way too much points and it takes too much time to proceed a `pgr_dijkstra` call.

Now, during the import phase, I need a way to remove all points and leave only those we're.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of PGRouting is that when you create a network from a line dataset, it will build a 'ways' table, but most importantly build a 'osm_nodes' table from the nodes of the 'ways'.

The actual routing takes place from node to node, and it sounds like here you have way too many nodes in the osm_nodes table.

I would suggest truncating (removing all) features from the osm_nodes table (create a backup just in case), and using an INSERT to load your preferred nodes into the osm_nodes table (using INSERT will let you map existing columns to the osm_nodes columns).

From there, it will now only use the nodes you have loaded to find any routes.

(note: I think you didn't finish the last sentence in your question...?)

Comment: Good. It's the same idea that I was already applying. Thank you very much!